# What is the shortcut key to skip a song in rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

When Rhythmbox is not active/not focused and when I am on some other application window.

How to skip/stop/resume songs that are playing in Rhythmbox. Is there any shortcut key to do that?

I know when I am on Ubuntu desktop I can press Alt+10 to get the focus of indicator applets from there I can navigate to Rhythmbox and use arrow keys to skip it ( <- / -> ) but is there any other direct shortcut to do this?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can use the fn and  >>| key that is on most keyboards. 
On my keyboard it is fn+f10 but just look for the key that looks like the fast-forward button.

You can also set the shortcuts for the keyboard

Open your Dash by pressing your "Super Key"
In the search bar enter in Keyboard 
and select "Keyboard"

[image]
[image]